# Centering a TextView vertically in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, center, vertical-alignment

I am trying to center a TextView in a LinearLayout and it is centering horizontaly but not vertically.

below is my code

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/taque"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Question"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:typeface="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `fill_parent` is deprecated use `match_parent`

Comment: make your textView height to `wrap_content`

Comment: What do you want to achieve finally ? your textview in middle of layout?

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/taque"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Question"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:typeface="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is `android:gravity="center"` for the TextView:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taque"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Question"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:typeface="normal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your layout looks fine apart from textview width and height.
Just change the width and height of textview from **match_parent** to **wrap_content**

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/taque"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `android:gravity=“center“` to your TextView and LinearLayout.